# Table cell padding issue when using vertical-align

Tags: html, css, html-table

In the following code, I can't see why the `B` character in the second column is not up against the top of the cell as I have set `vertical-align: top` and `padding: 0`. Likewise for the `C` character in the second row which I want at the bottom of its cell.

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

```css
* {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
td{
    padding:0;
}
.level-1{
    font-size: 4em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.level-2-1{
    font-size: 2em;
    vertical-align: top ;
}
.level-2-2{
    font-size: 2em;
    vertical-align: bottom ;
}
.level-3-1{
    font-size: 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.level-3-2{
    font-size: 1em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" class="level-1">A</td>
    <td class="level-2-1">B</td>
    <td class="level-3-1">C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="level-2-2">C</td>
    <td class="level-3-2">B</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all, because you left `line-height` at the default, `normal`. And second, because there is space reserved for potential over- and underlengths.

Comment: So the fix is please?

Comment: To decrease the line-height to a level that it looks okay to you. There is no one-size-fits-all answer here, because the extent of over-/underlengths will depend on the specific font.